# Where can I learn the syntax for VNC related commands and files?

Tags: vnc, tigervnc

This is really a question on learning strategy.

I am new to Linux and seem to know only two strategies:

- Get a 500 page text book and plow through it.  (I am plowing through a book on System Administration and another on shell script.)
- Follow concrete examples found in tutorials and posts on Q&A sites like this. (I do mostly this to install and set up things for immediate use.)

But I would like a middle strategy, where I get to "understand" a particular area, for example, VNC.

My problem is that I don't seem able to find any appropriate source (after hours and hours of search that only turn up more "tutorials" on concrete cases without explanation).

For example, I got a VNC (specifically TigerVNC) server going by creating, among other things, a file called 'xstartup' as follows, but without understanding what each line was doing.

```
#!/bin/sh 
[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
vncconfig -iconic &
dbus-launch --exit-with-session gnome-session &
```

Is there any source on VNC that would "cover the area" and "provide an understanding"? (Tigervnc.org was certainly not such a source.)

I am not even sure that this question fits the site's criteria for being on topic.  I would appreciate any comments on how I may improve it.

Comment: Are you really asking about the *syntax*? it's POSIX shell syntax rather than anything specific to VNC

Comment: @steeldriver. 'Syntax' was my way of asking how does each line (command or parameter) contribute toward VNC. I do realize I could research each thing separately (square bracket, `&&`, `xrdb`) and come to an understanding eventually. That would be like 'plowing through' 500 page books. But isn't there something more target or focused? It would explain the commands, parameters etc. and also why those elements should combine to form an xstartup file (systemd service unit, etc.) exactly as they do for VNC.

Comment: As far as I understand it, your question ist not about TigerVNC at all - but more about shell syntax, like @steeldriver suggests. It's not a "500 page book" to learn this. You are asking for multiple things - *why* the application needs them, and *how* they are implemented.

Comment: The book on shell scripting will explain the syntax... but there is a website that **might** help. Type a line of that script into https://explainshell.com/

Comment: @Panki. Yes, that's true in the sense that I might have the same question for another area, where I find either a 500 page book or "concrete-case this-is-what-you-do no-explanation" tutorials. Where does one find "this is how the thing works, these are the components" type explanation? On some topics, e.g. SSH, I do find such "targeted" explanations. But not on VNC.